# Are questions about generalized geodesics suitable for GIS despite being off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently asked [Which algorithms can be used to generate a euclidean embedding for a manifold given a pairwise distance matrix of geodesics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705667) at Stack Overflow, and @EvgenyPogrebnyak indicated that I might have more success at GIS, even though the question seems to be off-topic.

From my perspective, his primary argument is that even though the question is probably off-topic, the **GIS community** are precisely the people most likely to be able to answer it effectively, hence the question might not be unwelcome. This leaves me with three questions for Meta GIS SE:

1. Are questions about geodesics on arbitrary manifolds close enough to the realm of geodesy to be on-topic?
2. Are questions the GIS community might welcome allowed, despite technically being off-topic?
3. Would [Which algorithms can be used to generate a euclidean embedding for a manifold given a pairwise distance matrix of geodesics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705667) be welcome in the GIS community?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have not had a large volume of geodesy questions here but those that have been asked are usually answered and appear to be well received:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geodesy?sort=votes

To me, who only ever encounters geodesy in passing, your question looks to be on-topic for GIS SE and I think would be better asked here than at Stack Overflow because it currently contains no code.

However, I would also think that the Mathematics Stack Exchange might be a good site for it and that has a similar number of questions tagged geodesy:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geodesy?sort=votes

Wherever, you choose to ask it be sure to do that at only one site at a time, and if you decide to try asking the same question at a site or two other than Stack Overflow then be sure to delete behind you to avoid cross-posting.